# read mthod in BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, io, buffer

I saw in a tutorial that the int **read**(byte b [], int off, int len) in the **BufferedInputStream** class itself uses the read() method to read data.

So my question is, what is the difference between the normal mode and without using BufferedInputStream with using buffer? The buffer was supposed to read bytes in blocks to reduce costs, but here it is reading byte by byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that the simplest concrete `InputStream` is only required to implement just the method that reads a single byte (i.e. the `InputStream.read()` method).

It's also true that for such an underlying `InputStream` using a `BufferedInputStream` doesn't have any performance benefit, because `BufferedInputStream.read(byte b [], int off, int len)` depends on `InputStream.read(byte b [], int off, int len)` which (in `InputStream`) depends on the `InputStream.read()` method.

**However**

Many (most) of the "typical" `InputStream` subclasses that are used (for example `java.io.FileInputStream` for reading files, `java.net.SocketInputStream` for reading from network connections, `java.util.zip.ZipFile.ZipFileInputStrem` for reading data from zip files) do implement the `read(byte b [], int off, int len)` method.

For all these `InputStream` subclasses using a `BufferedInputStream` provides a tremendous performance benefit when reading single bytes (i.e. calling the `read()` method) because these classes do either a system call for fetching a single byte (`FileInputStream`), others allocate a byte array of length one and call `read(byte[] b)` (which in turn calls `read(b, 0, b.length)`) to read a single byte (`SocketInputStream`, `ZipFileInputStream`).

---

Note: the project that I used as base to find `InputStream` subclasses has 326 different `InputStream` subclasses. I didn't check every one of them to decide whether `BufferedInputStream` is beneficial on them, I just checked those few that I tend to use.